# What is the use of LogManager?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logging, asp.net-mvc-2

Can anyone explain what is the use of LogManager?

Answer (score 1):

> The log manager is a factory class
>   which has a series of methods that
>   allow us to instantiate logger
>   objects.

More info [here](http://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2010/11/20/how-to-integrate-logging-in-your-application-using-nlog).